# Average time taken to perform an activity

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column called Time taken to perform an activity (ex: go up the stairs). If the first time it took me 0:30 secs, and second time it took me 1:10 mins, I want to return a result of average 50 secs. 
The TimeElapsed is a datetime column

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '0:30'], [1, '1:10'], [2, '0:30']], columns=['Person Id', 'TimeElapsed'])
```

Output:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, '0:50'], [2, '0:30']], columns=['Person Id', 'Average TimeElapsed'])
```

I tried using

```
df2['AverageTimeElapsed'] = df[TimeElapsed'].dt.total_seconds()
```

but that doesn't work because it's not a timedelta function.

Comment: I assume you mean to have those as strings, `'0:30'`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will convert your column to time delta:

```
df["TimeElapsed"] = pd.to_timedelta("00:"+df["TimeElapsed"])
```

and you can then do your `total_seconds()`. In particular, if you look for average, you can simply get it from:

```
df["TimeElapsed"].mean()
```

**Update:**

Taking the comment below, this is the generic way to convert MM:SS time to seconds, as long as MM and SS are positive integers:

```
df["TimeElapsed"] = df["TimeElapsed"].apply(
    lambda T: datetime.timedelta(seconds=
         sum([x*y for x,y in zip([int(t) for t in T.split(":")], [60,1])])
    )
)
```

It is a bit unreadable, however. But I believe you get the point on converting a string into number/timedelta before further processing.

Comment: This gets the main part correct, but is prone to errors, for instance, if the time is ever larger than 10 minutes. Instead can try to format the `TimeElapsed` as `df.TimeElapsed.str[-8:-6].str.zfill(2) + ':' + df.TimeElapsed.str[-5:-3].str.zfill(2)+':'+ df.TimeElapsed.str[-2:]`

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you. ALollz might be right, but in my data I don't have anything greater than 10 minutes and I don't expect to have, so this will do. Thank you.